# MS Access: calculated field is slower than VBA code

Tags: ms-access, vba, continuous-forms

I have a subform (continous mode) in my main form which is used to add some articles with description, amount and price. In the footer of this sumform is a textfield which sums up all the entries of the subform by using `=sum([amount] * [price])`. That works so far.

Each time when I add a new entry in the subform, this textfield gets calculated. Now I also want to have this sum in a textfield of my main form (which actually also is not a problem). In "**`AfterUpdate`**"-event of my `combofield` in the continuous form I write the value of the `sum-textfield` to my textfield in the mainform. This initially also worked perfectly.

But now (I have no clue what changed), my textfield in the mainform doesn't get the new value, because the `vba` code runs faster than the calculated textfield in my subform-footer calculates its new value. It always writes the old value to the mainform. I discovered the problem using brakepoints in my code. So the old value gets written to the mainform before access is finished calculating the sum of all subform-entries.

Here's the code which I use to write the value from my subform textfield to my mainform textfield:

```
Private Sub txt_Article_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Refresh
    Me.Parent!txt_Amount = Int(Me.txt_SumOfAmountsInContinuousForm * 20 + 0.5) / 20
End Sub
```

I hope the description of my problem is somewhat understandable. It's a bit difficult to describe it :)
Is there a way to wait with my vba code until the sum-field has its new value calculated?

Thanks

Comment: Why use VBA? Textbox on main form can reference subform textbox in ControlSource expression. Are you saving calculated value to field?

Comment: I tried that already. My textbox on main form is connected to a table and therefore is the ControlSource already used.

Comment: So you are saving calculated value. Saving calculated value is usually a bad design, especially an aggregate calc. Save raw data and do calc when needed for output.